# Failed to send Javascript data to action by POST method with Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, yii2-advanced-app

I have a problem, I make the connection to my action from the Javascript through AJAX and send the data by POST. I declare the URL "/ controller / action" and it does not connect to the action, and AJAX gives me "parsererror". The strange thing is that I did one the same but to receive of an equal action and it did not give me error and I worked well

My JS File

```
function save_account(){
$.ajax({
    url: '/user/save-account',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'id_user': xxx,
        'email': xxx,
        'name': xxx,
        'type': xxx
    },
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
    },
    error : function (request, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

}

My action in controller

```
public function actionSaveAccount(){
    $model= new \frontend\models\ProfileForm();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            if($profile === $model->saveProfile()){
                // SAVED
            }else{
                // ERROR SAVED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My settings for URLs

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a request to a URL with a hypen (`-`), while the regex you are using for the route is the `w` character, which according to [regex101](http://regex101.com) is used for the following:

> \w
>
> Matches any letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Change the URL to save_account, and it will work.